# Link the edges and the nodes with a relationship class table in a geometric network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometric-network, relationship-class

I have a bus network in arcgis composed by:

- The Bus stops (points)
- The Bus lines (multilines)
- A relashionship table who link the stops and the line

[image]

So the relationship (Many-to-Many) contains a table who looks like that:

```
[ID_NODE, ID_LINE]
[1      , 1      ]
[2      , 1      ]
[3      , 1      ]
[2      , 2      ]
[4      , 2      ]
...
```

I'm now trying to create a geometric network based on those features.

When I create the geometric network I can add:

- The lines
- The stops

But not the many to many relashionship table !

[image]

It happens that a line go throught a stop but the bus don't serve this stop, so the line and the stop should be unconnected.

How can I add the information contained in my relationship table in the geometric network ?

Comment: For that relations, try to use (connectivity rules) tool to define the connections between your network points and lines. An example may can help [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/exercise-5-building-a-geometric-network.htm)

Comment: Ok with the rules you can said "An edge can or cannot be connected to this feature and how many connection can be made" but it doesn't help me to link a line with the stops. I want to take into account my many to many relationship !